# How to omit a particular key while pushing json objects to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, lodash

So, I have a JSON array of objects , which in turn contains other arrays of objects. This array of objects has no particular fixed structure as such so its very difficult for me do something like `delete mainArray[0].obj.subobj[1].objToOmit;`

So I have a key/object called `possibleAnswers` which I need to remove/omit. In my program I am pushing the contents of one array into another array. So while I am pushing the contents of first array of objects into another, I need to omit the `possibleAnswers` object from being pushed.

Is there any way or function that searches an array of objects and helps me omit the necessary key? Or what would be a solution as per your thoughts?

Example :

Here is a minimal example: https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb9fea0d
Edit: In the above JSON there is a key called `possibleMembers` which is wrong. its `possibleAnswers`

```
            var collectObservationsFromConceptSets = function () {
            $scope.consultation.observations = [];
            _.each($scope.consultation.selectedObsTemplates, function (conceptSetSection) {
                if (conceptSetSection.observations) {
                    _.each(conceptSetSection.observations, function (obs) {
                        $scope.consultation.observations.push(obs);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

In the above code while pushing the object into another array, how can I omit the `possibleAnswers` keys? Is there a way to omit?

Thanks a lot people! Both the answers are correct and have generated the exact correct output. Unfortunately I can only select 1 answer as correct and its going to be random.

Comment: Recursively search for `possibleAnswers` keys and `delete` them?

Comment: @CertainPerformance How do I do that? I'll also try posting the JSON , so that you will get a more clearer picture of what I need

Comment: It will help you get better answers if you can post an example of the array you are starting with.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Also I dont know the structure of my JSON, its not a fixed one, so I wouldn't know how would I traverse it

Comment: @MarkMeyer Yes. Will post the JSON

Comment: That's why you'd use a recursive function. Please post an example of the code you're working with

Comment: @CertainPerformance Have uploaded the JSON

Comment: @MarkMeyer Uploaded the JSOn

Comment: For a question to be on-topic, you should put all the relevant code in the question itself - trim it down to a [MCVE], 1.6 MB worth of JSON to go through is too much

Comment: @krishnanspace, you just need to paste an example that shows the problem (in the question). I don't think anyone will want to download and open an unknown 1.6MB file to answer a question.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry . I will post a minimal example

Comment: @CertainPerformance Sorry. Will post a minimal example

Comment: @MarkMeyer Added a minimal example

Comment: @CertainPerformance Added a minimal example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive omit that uses [`_.transform()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#transform) to iterate and ignore one or more keys in an array:

```js
const omitRecursive = (keys, obj) => _.transform(obj, (acc, v, k) => {
  // if key is view, and it and has an id value replace it with equivalent from views
  if(keys.includes(k)) return;
  
  acc[k] = _.isObject(v) ? omitRecursive(keys, v) : v;
});

const data = [{"observations":[{"possibleAnswers":[],"groupMembers":[{"possibleAnswers":[]},{"groupMembers":[{"possibleMembers":[]},{"possibleMembers":[]}]}]}]},{"observations":"Same as above"},{"observations":"Same as above"}];

const result = omitRecursive(['possibleAnswers'], data);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try it out and let you know!

Comment: Can you guide me in improving my JS skills?

Comment: I really like this books:
JavaScript: The Good Parts • Douglas Crockford, 
Learning JavaScript Design Patterns • Addy Osmani, 
Javascript Allongé • Reginald Braithwait,

Comment: Thanks! Will definitely check those out

Comment: I really like [egghead](https://egghead.io/courses), and https://www.freecodecamp.org/ Good luck!

Comment: Note that the books are a bit old, but they'll give you got overview of the language, and it's features.

Answer (score 1):

This function will remove all 'possibleAnswers' if called on your original array like `removeKey(arr, 'possibleAnswers')`

```
function removeKey(objOrArr, keyToRemove) {
  if (Array.isArray(objOrArr)) {
    objOrArr.forEach(o => removeKey(o, keyToRemove));
  } else if (typeof objOrArr === 'object') {
    delete objOrArr[keyToRemove];
    Object.values(objOrArr).forEach(v => removeKey(v, keyToRemove));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it out and let you know!